# Does the CSS cascade apply significance based on the order in which you add classes to HTML elements?

Tags: css

Quite confused here.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one
{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.two
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<body>
<p class="two one"> Test!!!!!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Why is Test bold? I'm clearly defining "normal" for the font weight "after" the bolded one?

I thought CSS did the cascading based on what order the classes were added right? Not the location in the file?

Comment: look at this picture it will explain it all http://laughingsquid.com/css-is-awesome/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS doesn't care what order you specify the classes inside your `class` attribute.

Here, both classes have *equal specificity*, so the class lower down in your CSS "wins".

[Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) - a well written article explaining specificity.

Pointless demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/JwhmE/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't go off the order of the classes on the div but the order they are defined in the `style` rule.

Comment: So if they styles are included in separate files, is it the "Second" file that's used?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the last file to be referenced. A `style` rule in the `html` document will also overwrite the linked style sheet